# Exception caught by widgets library, BoxConstraints has a negative minimum width

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used State less Widget for Elevated Button in project and the values Widget are passed down to elevated button Constructor so when I run project the following exception is thrown the following is Elevated Button

```
import 'package:cashmate_fo/utility/text_style.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class ElevatedButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      final VoidCallback? onPressed;
      Color color;
      String text;
      double width;
      double height;
      ElevatedButtonWidget({
        this.width = 0.0,
        this.height = 0.0,
        this.color = Colors.indigo,
        required this.onPressed,
        required this.text,
        Key? key,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: textStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              onSurface: Colors.brown,
              primary: color,
              //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20,vertical: 20)
              minimumSize: Size(width, height),
              side: BorderSide(width: 1.5, color: Colors.indigo.shade500),
              shape:
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
        );
      }
    }
```

And this is the exception which is thrown

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building ElevatedButton(style: ButtonStyle#e56ec(textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(null), backgroundColor: _ElevatedButtonDefaultBackground#0293c, foregroundColor: _ElevatedButtonDefaultForeground#a3d81, minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(-100.0, 0.0)), side: MaterialStateProperty.all(BorderSide(Color(0xff3f51b5), 1.5, BorderStyle.solid)), shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(BorderSide(Color(0xff000000), 0.0, BorderStyle.none), BorderRadius.circular(10.0)))), dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, _InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#0ae7b]], state: _ButtonStyleState#6cb82(materialStates: {})):
BoxConstraints has a negative minimum width.
The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(-100.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=Infinity; NOT NORMALIZED)
The relevant error-causing widget was
ElevatedButton
lib\widgets\elevated_button_widget.dart:21
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reason For this beacause you specified your with and height as 0.0

You need to remove the default value or add required to width and height

```
final double width;
final double height;
```

and required parameters

also you can fix this removing

```
minimumSize: Size(width, height),
```

on elevated button

Comment: the issue is because ``width`` was provided value ``-100`` !!